# How to send mass payments using rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, paypal, masspay

I'm using Rails and need to send money to my users.

Here is my function:

```
    def self.send_money(to_email, how_much_in_cents, options = {})
credentials = {
  "USER" => API_USERNAME,
  "PWD" => API_PASSWORD,
  "SIGNATURE" => API_SIGNATURE,
}

params = {
  "METHOD" => "MassPay",
  "CURRENCYCODE" => "USD",
  "RECEIVERTYPE" => "EmailAddress",
  "L_EMAIL0" => to_email,
  "L_AMT0" => ((how_much_in_cents.to_i)/100.to_f).to_s,
  "VERSION" => "51.0"
}

endpoint = RAILS_ENV == 'production' ? "https://api-3t.paypal.com" : "https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com"
url = URI.parse(endpoint)
http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
http.use_ssl = true
all_params = credentials.merge(params)
stringified_params = all_params.collect { |tuple| "#{tuple.first}=#{CGI.escape(tuple.last)}" }.join("&")

response = http.post("/nvp", stringified_params)
 end
```

I should put in some helpers files?

I want to use it in my views, something like:

```
 <%@merchants each do%>
   <%@merchant(current_user.email, 100)%>
 <%end%>
```

or just transfer array of users in controller.

Where I should put this function to make it right ?

Comment: if you were able to do it?

Comment: @ManishShrivastava: No

Comment: well, Now I am trying and If I will be able to do that I will let you know. Thanks for respose skrypalyk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should assign `@merchants` in your controller and create a function `show_merchant` in you helper like this :

```
def show_mercant(merchant, email, value)
  ...
end
```

and use it in your view like this :

```
<% @merchants.each do |merchant| %>
  <%= show_merchant(merchant, current_user.email, 100) %>
<% end %>
```

I think your function `send_money` has nothing to do here, right?

Comment: why do you think I don't need it ?

Comment: it isn't related directly to your problem.